# Preventing double-output in python FileHandler when log paths overlap

Tags: python, logging

The following code results in the same log message being output twice:

```
log1 = logging.getLogger('foo')
log1.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('log.txt'))
log2 = logging.getLogger('foo.bar')
log2.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('log.txt'))

log2.warn("test message")
```

I realize that this is because 'foo.bar' matches both the 'foo' and 'foo.bar' paths, so both loggers get the message.  My question is: is there any way to prevent this behaviour other than making sure I never have two loggers pointing to the same file in the same log path?

Answer (score 3):

You can tell `log2` [not to propagate messages](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) to the handlers of ancestor loggers:

```
log2.propagate = False
```

---

```
import logging

log1 = logging.getLogger('foo')
log1.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('log.txt'))
log2 = logging.getLogger('foo.bar')
log2.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('log.txt'))
log2.propagate = False
log2.warn("test message")
```

writes `test message` only once in `log.txt`.